# how to remove duplicate numbers? more of the same values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code combines values from two matrices and lists them side by side. T works as I need properly.
We are trying to remove the field where 2 identical values are located. This can be better seen in the example below

my code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import sys

b=np.array([[13,14,15],
           [22,23,24],
           [31,32,33]])
#print(b)
d=np.array([100,200,300,400,500])

b[-1,:] = d[:b.shape[1]] # last row
b[:-1,-1] = d[b.shape[1]:]

val1 = np.hstack(b[::-1])
val2 = np.hstack([d[i:i+b.shape[1]] for i in range(b.shape[0])])
res = zip(val1, val2)
for i, j in res:
    l=[i, j]
    print(l)
```

my output

```
[100, 100]
[200, 200]
[300, 300]
[22, 200]
[23, 300]
[500, 400]
[13, 300]
[14, 400]
[400, 500]
```

My code combines values from two matrices and lists them side by side. T works as I need properly.
We are trying to remove the field where 2 identical values are located. This can be better seen in the example below

I would need to remove matrices in my output that contain the same numbers. As you can see in the output below
The matrices do not always have to be the same and do not have to match the same iterations

required output

```
[22, 200]
[23, 300]
[500, 400]
[13, 300]
[14, 400]
[400, 500]
```

Comment: Wouldn't simple `if(i != j):` in the last loop work?

Comment: Please take care to validate your past answers if you want more people to help you and also help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Find where the values are different and only concatenate those values.

```
>>> # using val1 and val2 from the question
>>> mask = np.where(val1!=val2)
>>> mask
(array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64),)
>>> np.vstack((val1[mask],val2[mask]))
array([[ 22,  23, 500,  13,  14, 400],
       [200, 300, 400, 300, 400, 500]])
>>> np.vstack((val1[mask],val2[mask])).T
array([[ 22, 200],
       [ 23, 300],
       [500, 400],
       [ 13, 300],
       [ 14, 400],
       [400, 500]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as comparing the two arrays and using the result as a boolean index:

```
np.stack([val1, val2], axis=1)[val1 != val2]
```